# How to share data between Django files within one project?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm a Django newbie, so I'm trying to learn by slowly build my own expenses and income website on PythonAnywhere.

I know my project is not properly spec'd, but **it works perfectly ... except for one thing:** **The home page can pull data from my expenses table but not my income table.  There's no error, it just returns zero records.**

I'm convinced the problem is related to the fact that I've put income-related items in a separate income.py file.  I don't want to merge the income stuff into the larger views.py file.

**Can you please give me some suggestions on how I can access the Income table data from the HomePageView in views.py?**

Thanks, Jason

### Django Site Structure:

```
Django01
   ---Django01
         __init__.py
         asgi.py
         income.py          # created later, contains income_list(request)
         models.py          # contains definitions for both an Expenses table and an Income table
         settings.py
         urls.py            # holds all urls for site
         views.py           # contains HomePageView(TemplateView) and expense_list(request)
         wsgi.py
   ---static
   ---templates
         ---Django01
               base.html
               expenses_list.html
               home.html       # Page where I'd like to access BOTH Expense and Income table
               incomes_list.html
```

### views.py:

```
# ===============================================================================
# views.py
# ===============================================================================
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Expenses, Income
from datetime import date, datetime
from django.db.models import Count, Sum


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Home Page
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['base_template'] = "base.html"

        # Create Date Range (Today - 2 Years)
        todays_date       = date.today()
        current_year      = todays_date.year
        last_year         = int(current_year) - 1
        start_range       = str(last_year) + "-01-01"
        end_range         = str(last_year) + "-12-31"

        # Create Frequent Expense Sellers List <--- WORKS GREAT!
        sellers_recordset = Expenses.objects.filter(xdate__range=[start_range, end_range]).values('xseller','xcategory').exclude(xseller__exact='').annotate(count=Count('xseller')).order_by('-count', 'xseller')[:10:1]
        context['sellers_list'] = sellers_recordset

        # Create Frequent Income Sources List <--- NOT WORKING. RETURNS EMPTY, NO ERROR, WHY???
        payers_recordset = Income.objects.filter(idate__range=[start_range, end_range]).values('ipayer','isource').exclude(ipayer__exact='').annotate(count=Count('ipayer')).order_by('-count', 'ipayer')[:10:1]
        context['payers_list'] = payers_recordset

        return context


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expense List Page  <--- WORKS GREAT!
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@login_required
def expense_list(request):

    # Are there Parameters in HTTP Query String?
    param_year     = request.GET.get('year','')
    param_seller   = request.GET.get('seller','')
    param_category = request.GET.get('category','')
    param_vacation = request.GET.get('vacation','')

    # Set Default Years
    todays_date = date.today()
    current_year  = todays_date.year
    next_year     = current_year + 1
    previous_year = current_year - 1

    # Filter Expenses based on Parameters
    if param_year != "":
        current_year      = int(param_year)
        next_year         = current_year + 1
        previous_year     = current_year - 1
        start_range       = str(current_year) + "-01-01"
        end_range         = str(current_year) + "-12-31"
        expense_recordset = Expenses.objects.filter(xdate__range=[start_range, end_range]).order_by('-xdate')
        show_year         = True
    elif param_seller != "":
        expense_recordset = Expenses.objects.filter(xseller=param_seller).order_by('-xdate')
        show_year = False
    elif param_category != "":
        expense_recordset = Expenses.objects.filter(xcategory=param_category).order_by('-xdate')
        show_year = False
    elif param_vacation != "":
        expense_recordset = Expenses.objects.filter(xvacation=param_vacation).order_by('-xdate')
        show_year = False
    else:
        expense_recordset = Expenses.objects.filter(xdate__gte="2021-01-01").order_by('-xdate')
        show_year = True

    # Get Count & Totals
    expense_count = expense_recordset.all().count()
    expense_total = expense_recordset.all().aggregate(Sum('xamount')).get('xamount__sum', 0.00)

    # Create Context to Send to Template
    context = {
        'base_template' : "base.html",
        'show_year'     : show_year,
        'next_year'     : next_year,
        'current_year'  : current_year,
        'previous_year' : previous_year,
        'expense_count' : expense_count,
        'expense_list'  : expense_recordset,
        'expense_total' : expense_total
    }

    return render(request, 'expense_list.html', context=context)
```

### income.py:

```
# ===============================================================================
# income.py
# ===============================================================================
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Income
from datetime import datetime, date
from django.db.models import Count, Sum

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Incomes List Page  <--- WORKS GREAT!
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@login_required
def income_list(request):

    # Are there Parameters in HTTP Query String?
    param_year   = request.GET.get('year','')
    param_payer  = request.GET.get('payer','')
    param_source = request.GET.get('source','')

    # Set Default Years
    todays_date   = date.today()
    current_year  = todays_date.year
    next_year     = current_year + 1
    previous_year = current_year - 1

    # Filter Income based on Parameters
    if param_year != "":
        current_year      = int(param_year)
        next_year         = current_year + 1
        previous_year     = current_year - 1
        start_range       = str(current_year) + "-01-01"
        end_range         = str(current_year) + "-12-31"
        income_recordset  = Income.objects.filter(idate__range=[start_range, end_range]).order_by('-idate')
        show_year         = True
    elif param_payer != "":
        income_recordset  = Income.objects.filter(ipayer=param_payer).order_by('-idate')
        show_year         = False
    elif param_source != "":
        income_recordset  = Income.objects.filter(isource=param_source).order_by('-idate')
        show_year         = False
    else:
        income_recordset  = Income.objects.filter(idate__gte='2021-01-01').order_by('-idate')
        show_year         = True

    # Get Count & Totals
    income_count = income_recordset.all().count()
    income_total = income_recordset.all().aggregate(Sum('iamount')).get('iamount__sum', 0.00)

    # Create Context to Send to Template
    context = {
        'base_template' : "base.html",
        'show_year'     : show_year,
        'next_year'     : next_year,
        'current_year'  : current_year,
        'previous_year' : previous_year,
        'income_count'  : income_count,
        'income_list'   : income_recordset,
        'income_total'  : income_total
    }

    return render(request, 'income_list.html', context=context)
```

### models.py:

```
# ===============================================================================
# models.py
# ===============================================================================
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expenses Table
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Expenses(models.Model):

    # Fields
    xid = models.AutoField(db_column='xID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='xDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xseller = models.CharField(db_column='xSeller', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xamount = models.DecimalField(db_column='xAmount', max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xcategory = models.CharField(db_column='xCategory', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xwith = models.CharField(db_column='xWith', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xpresent = models.CharField(db_column='xPresent', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xvacation = models.CharField(db_column='xVacation', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xnotes = models.CharField(db_column='xNotes', max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    # Metadata
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Expenses'
        app_label  = 'Expenses'         # Added to Alleviate RunTime Error

    # Methods
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular instance of MyModelName."""
        return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the MyModelName object (in Admin site etc.)."""
        return self.my_field_name


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Income Table
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Income(models.Model):

    # Fields
    iid = models.AutoField(db_column='iID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    idate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='iDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ipayer = models.CharField(db_column='iPayer', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    iamount = models.DecimalField(db_column='iAmount', max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    isource = models.CharField(db_column='iSource', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    inotes = models.CharField(db_column='iNotes', max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    # Metadata
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Income'
        app_label  = 'Expenses'         # Added to Alleviate RunTime Error

    # Methods
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular instance of MyModelName."""
        return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the MyModelName object (in Admin site etc.)."""
        return self.my_field_name
```

### urls.py:

```
# ===============================================================================
# urls.py
# ===============================================================================
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from .views import HomePageView, expense_list
from .income import income_list

urlpatterns = [
    path('',                 HomePageView.as_view(),    name='home'),
    path('expense_list/',    expense_list,              name='expense_list'),
    path('income_list/',     income_list,               name='income_list'),
    path('accounts/',        include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/',           admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: If your query is returning no records, then that suggests that you have no records that match the criteria in your database. Try using the manage.py shell to experiment with the query to see why it might not be behaving the way you expect it to.

Comment: @Glenn: You were right!  My end_range variable in views.py was set to last_year rather than current_year and that excluded the records I needed.  Thanks for the help! If you post this as an answer then I'll be happy to select it.